# How to get top 5 history rows of each sql job?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get top 5 (latest) of each sql job.
I tried to query it like this

```
SELECT Pr1.job_ID,MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time) LastRun, COUNT(*) num
FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory Pr1 
JOIN MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory Pr2
    ON MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time) = MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr2.run_date, Pr2.run_time)
     AND Pr1.job_ID = Pr2.job_ID
GROUP BY Pr1.job_ID, MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time)
HAVING COUNT (*) <= 5
ORDER BY job_ID, MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time)
```

But this query runs forever. I am using sql-server.

i also tried with a recommendation from below.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT jo.name,Pr1.job_ID, Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time,pr1.run_status,
          Count(*) Over (Partition By Pr1.job_ID,Pr1.run_date,Pr1.run_time) As num,
          Row_Number() Over (Partition By Pr1.job_ID,Pr1.run_date,Pr1.run_time
                             Order By  pr1.run_date desc--, pr1.run_time desc
                             ) As Rn
   FROM   MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory Pr1 
   join MSDB.dbo.sysjobs jo on jo.job_id=pr1.job_id
   JOIN MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory Pr2 
         ON Pr1.job_ID = Pr2.job_ID --and pr1.run_status=pr2.run_status
         and pr1.run_date >=pr2.run_date and pr1.run_time >=pr2.run_time 
)
SELECT name,job_ID, run_date, run_time,run_status
FROM CTE
WHERE num <= 3 AND Rn = 1
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using, `top 5` means that you use sql-server?

Comment: It's running forever because you use the sclar valued function `Agent_datetime`.

Comment: ok How do i fix pls? and yes i am on sql-server

Comment: You fix it by not using the function.

Comment: is there any way i can have the time and date of the job running?

Comment: Of course, but you haven't shown what `Agent_datetime` does or why you can't get the time and date of the job running.

Comment: Which 5 rows you need for each job? Latest ? Slowest? You may want to try window function rownumber.

Comment: i get the date time values from run_date and run_time

Comment: @aye26: But what does `Agent_datetime` return, what do you want to show?

Comment: @Tim3880 i am trying to get the latest and how ca i use what you suggested pls?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it returns the datetime (2014-11-28 07:20:00.000)

Comment: Your join condition is pretty pointless since you are using the function with the same values here: `ON MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time) = MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time)`

Comment: Your last query (Tim Schmelter's suggestion) runs in under a second on my SQL Servers.  To go any further we will need to see the actual query plan.  Save this as a `*.sqlplan` file from Management Studio and the post that (or a link) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running forever because you use the scalar valued function `Agent_datetime`. If you use a query that doesn't need those functions the query optimizer can do it's job and use indexes.

You can simplify your task with window functions and a common-table-expression(CTE). Following groups by  the column `job_ID` and returns the latest record of each group according to the  `run_date` and `run_time` columns:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Pr1.job_ID, Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time,
          Count(*) Over (Partition By Pr1.job_ID) As num,
          Row_Number() Over (Partition By Pr1.job_ID 
                             Order By Pr1.run_date DESC, Pr1.run_time DESC) As Rn
   FROM   MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory
)
SELECT job_ID, run_date, run_time
FROM CTE
WHERE num <= 3 AND Rn = 1
```

Note that i've removed your pointless join condition and the self-join:

```
ON MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time) 
 = MSDB.dbo.Agent_datetime(Pr1.run_date, Pr1.run_time)
```

Comment: try that with MeaningfulDateTimeColumn =>  Order By  pr1.run_date desc, pr1.run_time desc. it still runs forever

Comment: @aye26: do you still use the Agent_datetime function?

Comment: @aye26: why do you need to self join the table at all? I have edited  my answer

Comment: @aye26: it helps if you put an index on `job_id` and a composite indexe on the columns `run_date DESC`+ `run_time DESC`, if they don't already  exist(i assume that `jobID` is already a foreign-key).

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select pr.*
from (select pr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pr.job_id
                                order by pr.run_date desc, pr.run_time desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory pr
     ) pr
where seqnum <= 5;
```